If $x=x_0$ is a vertical asymptote, may exist $f(x_{0})$?
I have to plot a function $f$ such that

$f$ is even;
$x=1$ is a vertical asymptote;
$y=2$ is an horizontal asymptote;
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^{+}}f(x)=\infty$;
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^{-}}f(x)=\infty$;
$f(x)\geq2$ if $0<x<1$;
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-1^{-}}f(x)=0$;
$f$ is increasing at $[1,+\infty)$;
the domain of $f$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$

What I did was:

My question is, $x=0$ and $x=\pm1$ are vertical asymptotes, but they also have to be in the domain. So, can I take any value to them?

You can take any value for $f(0)$, but for $f(1)=f(-1)$ you must choose a value $\le0$, for $f$ to be increasing on $[1,\infty)$, which includes $1$.

@AnneBauval so the curve can "touch" the asymptote?

Here it has to, by definition of a vertical asymptote.

As a practical example: $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ has $f(1)=f(-1)=0$, and the graph $y=f(x)$ has vertical asymptotes $x=\pm 1$.
